# Remove specific slug in with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a Wordpress site web in localhost with XAMPP. Now I have a URL like this:

```
http://localhost:82/subdirectory/images.html/nggallery/tags/[tagname]
```

Now I want this:

```
http:// localhost:82/subdirectory/images/nggallery/[tagname]
```

To remove tags, I've tried many codes, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^tags/(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

but doesn't work.
Help me, please.

---

I'm using **WordPress**, my htaccess file looks like this

```
# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteBase /subdirectory/ 

  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
  RewriteRule . /subdirectory/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before answering, a better idea than using htaccess for this is to use Wordpress' rewrite modules.

Anyway, you need to put your specific rules **before** Wordpress' main rule.

You can replace your current code by this one in your htaccess (which has to be in your `subdirectory` folder)

```
# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteBase /subdirectory/ 

  # redirect /.../tags/XXX to /.../XXX
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /images\.html/nggallery/tags/([^\s\?]+)\s [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ images/nggallery/%1? [R=301,L]

  # internally rewrite /.../XXX to /.../tags/XXX
  RewriteRule ^images/nggallery/(.+)$ images.html/nggallery/tags/$1 [L]

  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: I tried this:
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /images\.html/nggallery/tags/([^\s\?]+)\s [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ images/nggallery/%1? [R=301,L] but if I'm going to www.site.com/subdirectory/images.html, I'm taken here: www.site.com/images

Comment: Kinda weird, i just tested and it's working as expected. Where is your htaccess located ? In your `subdirectory` folder ?

Comment: Sure. Now I tried this and seem work: RewriteRule ^images.html$ /subdirectory/images [R=301,L]. The new URL is http://www.example.com/subdirectory/images (without .html) but I receive a 404 error :(

Comment: Also with you code: RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /images\.html/nggalleries/tags/([^\s\?]+)\s [NC] RewriteRule ^images/nggalleries/%1? [R=301,L] If I go to subdirectory/images.html, I'm redirect to subdirectory/images but with 404 error

Comment: I don't understand when you say `/subdirectory/images.html` redirects to `/subdirectory/images` because my code only redirects `/subdirectory/images.html/nggallery/tags/something` to `/subdirectory/images/nggallery/something`

Comment: Now I'm testing the codes on Aruba. I think that the updates of .htaccess are not instant because I receive in delay the behavior changes. So I confused the behavior of the different codes. Indeed, now with the same code I don't see the same behavior that I said.

Comment: Well i suggest you to try my code (in my answer) again but before, clear your browser's cache (because 301 rules are stored into it) or try it with another browser (and eventually, wait a bit)

Comment: So, the your code doesn't work, nothing changes: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /images\.html/nggallery/tags/([^\s\?]+)\s [NC] RewriteRule ^images/nggallery/%1? [R=301,L]`
 if I go on /subdirectory/images.html/nggallery/tags/something I see the same URL with the correct page, but not /subdirectory/images/nggallery/something

Comment: What is `something` when you try it ? Do you have a query string appened ? To make things easier, could you show me the real url (without your domain name) you're trying to reach ?

Comment: The real url is: `http://www.site.it/subdirectory/immagini.html/nggallery/tags/capelli`

Comment: I suppose you have changed `images` by `immagini` in my code ? Same for `subdirectory` except if you're really testing with `subdirectory`. Make sure my rules are placed **before** WordPress' main rule (as in my code). If it still does not work, i don't know why. On my side, it is working with the same code

Comment: Sure, my real code is: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /immagini\.html/nggallery/tags/([^\s\?]+)\s [NC] RewriteRule ^immagini/nggallery/%1? [R=301,L]` and I've placed it BEFORE of wordpress main rule. I've not insert `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews` because I receive 500 server error. Is possibile that some php codes could interfer with your rule?

Comment: I don't think so. But i see one problem in the code you pasted: you must have a space between `^` and `immagini` in `RewriteRule` directive (**only for this rule** not the second). To make sure, simply copy/paste my code and replace `images` by `immagini`

Comment: Ok, now work and I receive this URL: `http://www.site.it/subdirectory/immagini/nggallery/capelli` but with 404 error :(

Comment: Don't you have forgotten my second `RewriteRule` which rewrites this url back to its original format ?

Comment: With the second rewriterule: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /immagini\.html/nggallery/tags/([^\s\?]+)\s [NC] RewriteRule ^ immagini/nggallery/%1? [R=301,L] RewriteRule ^immagini/nggallery/(.+)$ immagini.html/nggallery/tags/$1 [L]`

Comment: Do you have access to your server logs ? Even if i don't see any reason it's not working. Maybe it's a conflict problem with WordPress when new url is rewritten back to its original format

Comment: `[Tue Dec 30 20:12:24 2014] [alert] [client xxx.xx.xx.xx:56410] - www.site.it - /web/htdocs/www.site.it/home/subdirectory/.htaccess: Option FollowSymLinks not allowed here
[Tue Dec 30 20:12:11 2014] [alert] [client xxx.xx.xx.xx:56347] - www.site.it - /web/htdocs/www.site.it/home/subdirectory/.htaccess: Option FollowSymLinks not allowed here
[Tue Dec 30 20:11:36 2014] [alert] [client xxx.xx.xx.xx:56302] - www.site.it - /web/htdocs/www.site.it/home/subdirectory/.htaccess: Option FollowSymLinks not allowed here`

Comment: Try replacing `+FollowSymLinks` by `+SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` or try removing `Option` line entirely

Comment: Sure, I removed +FollowSymLinks because I receive 500 server error, but the issue is the same (error 404). I tried Option +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch but I have always 500 server error.

Comment: I tried also in localhost with XAMPP and I have the same issue, 404 error :/

Comment: Hmmm... It's hard to debug it from a distance. This is totally weird, i don't know why it is not working i'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

try 
http:// localhost:82/subdirectory/images/nggallery/[tagname]

```
RewriteRule ^nggallery/tags/(.*)$ http://localhost:82/subdirectory/images/nggallery/$1
```

Comment: Doesn't work. My code is
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdirectory/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subdirectory/index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^nggallery/tags/(.*)$ http://localhost:82/subdirectory/images/nggallery/$1
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: This hardcodes server name and port, which probably should be avoided. (In case you ever want/need to change the port, it's one less place to change it. Looking at [RewriteRule docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), it is apparently discarded anyway.)